# OpenProject pg_restore - input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore my OpenProject's database created with the command

```
sudo openproject run backup
```

this command created the file `postgresql-dump-20190722131834.pgdump` which I'm trying to restore with the command

```
pg_restore --host=localhost --dbname=openproject postgresql-dump-20190722131834.pgdump
```

but it returns me the error

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

I've also tried to att the `--format=c` option to the `pg_restore` command, but the error changes to

```
pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
```

The script which OpenProject runs to create a PostgreSQL backup is:

```
dump_postgresql() {
  dst="${TARGET}/postgresql-dump-${timestamp}.pgdump"
  touch "$dst" && chmod 0640 "$dst"
  pg_dump -Fc $DATABASE_URL > $dst

  echo " done" >&2
  echo "$dst"
}
```

I've also noticed that `pg_dump` prints a lot of warnings like this:

```
pg_dump: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used
```

I'm trying to restore the database on a machine which runs Ubuntu 18.04 and PostgreSQL 10.

This is the result of the command `head postgresql-dump-20190722131834.pgdump` (I've put it in a screenshot because there are some invalid characters which I can't copy-paste):
[image: head command results]

Comment: How is this backup taken? Maybe that `.pgdump` is a dump in plain text format which is essentially a SQL script that you need to run through `psql`. What do you see with `head postgresql-dump-20190722131834.pgdump`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've updated my question with the result. I've found some invalid characters in that file, but I don't know if it means that the file is corrupted or that it's not a plain-text format...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll post an answer because it might be useful to someone else.

As the [screenshot in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzPGh.png) displays, there is an error in the `/home/openproject/.postgresqlrc` file on the server on which I've run the backup.

The format of that file was not correct: I've fixed it by following the format described [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/postgresqlrc.5.html) and when I had run the next backup I get no errors, and I was also able to restore that backup successfully.